# Cat stubbornly keeps repeating behaviour she's not supposed to do (and knows)

Tags: cats, behavior, chewing

I have a set of furniture for my tv and dvds that my cat recently has discovered as something fun to climb on. For that she needs to start from the window-frame, jump behind the curtain and get on a closet.

I don't want her to climb on it, because she could cause damage by chewing, or throwing dvds on the ground, damaging the boxes and scratching the dvds.

I make it very clear that she's not allowed to climb the furniture set, by firmly saying 'no!' (and body language) and grabbing her by the neck and taking her off the furniture, if she persists. This usually works, as shouting or standing up from the couch normally makes her turn back. But sometimes she just rushes forward to reach as much as she can, before I have time to react.

**The question**

Is this just cats being cats, or might this be a sign of boredom? What can I do to get a more permanent solution?

*PS: Sort of funny, she resets the clock above the furniture, by moving the big hand (she has to stand on dvds and stretch real high to do that).*

Comment: You might find the answers to this question helpful: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/why-my-cat-is-doing-acts-of-sabotage

Comment: @mhwombat: Cool! What I sort of fear is that my cat might be showing signs of boredom, despite having plenty of toys, a massive scratch post to climb on (2 meters high) and me playing with her easily beyond 1 hour a day. Your link doesn't go into detail into this, so, what would be the best option?

Answer (score 4):

Cats have a natural need to climb in the wild - to literally save their life against predators and allow them to see to hunt - and without other alternatives they will ignore arbitrary rules.  A better way of thinking is to provide an *acceptable alternative* to something you don't like...like in this case a cat tree, or a good scratch post to keep a cat from clawing the carpet or sofa.

You could even move the clock to above the new tree to allow the cat to have fun stopping the hand!

Comment: She has a cat tree 2,2 meters high and at least a meter wide :).